# How to convert voltage into digital signals?

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement, 555

How do I convert voltage into digital signals or pulses? For some reason I have to get voltage readings of the battery connected to the UPS of the computer systems.

For that purpose I am designing a device and computer program to monitor voltage and current readings.
Previously I designed an Ohm meter via a 555 timer. When R2 is change the timer generates relative (to the resistor) frequency of pulses and my program can easily detect the change in the value of resistor. So, Can I use 555 timer for my purpose since its equation for frequency has no variable for voltage and current?

Schematic of the circuit will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general what you are looking for is a *analog to digital converter*, or A/D for short.  There are many different types.  Each different technology has its own tradeoff between speed, accuracy, resolution, cost, and other parameters.

One method of making a number from a analog parameter is to have the parameter change the frequency of a oscillator as it seem you did with your 555 timer, then measure the frequency.  There are many other ways too.  Nowadays, just about every microcontroller comes with a A/D converter built in.  10 bits is quite common.  Some low end ones may only have 8 bits, and 12 bits is available too.  Beyond that the anlog requirements get difficult to meet with the same technology the micro is fabricated with, so you pretty much need a external A/D for more than 12 bits.

The battery in your UPS may be isolated from the output or not at the same ground reference, so some care must be taken to measure its voltage and get the data into your PC.  My first knee jerk reaction is to put a small micro on the battery circuit.  It measures the battery voltage locally, then sends the resulting digital data serially over a single opto-coupler to another micro that interfaces to the PC via USB, or perhaps directly to the PC's COM port.

Comment: @Olin-Yeah, I mean the same.Please let me know the name of that micro-controller. Thanks

Comment: @Farid: Same *what*?  As for the micro, there are many many that have A/Ds built in.  If this is cost-sensitive, look at some of the low end PIC 16s.

Answer (score 1):

As Olin said- "Nowadays, just about every microcontroller comes with a A/D converter built in." What accuracy do you want? What special requirements do you have that mean that "just about every microcontroller" is not enough information?

If you go to eg www.digikey.com and search for
  microcontroller adc
 you will get [this list](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/cat/integrated-circuits-ics/embedded-microcontrollers/2556109?k=microcontroller%20adc) of about 300 parts. Most of these will probably meet your need. If you want a more detailed answer than that you will need to provide more information about your requirement.

If you have no more detailed information then the above list is as good an answer as can be provided.

As a guide, selecting the cheapest available in stock item from Digikey from that table gives the [pic10f220](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41270E.pdf) at $us0.72 /1. This may not be best for your task but is as good as any for  the information provided. It has 2 x 8 bit ADC converters.

For $US0.91/1 you get the amazingly well featured [STM8s...](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/DM00024550.pdf) with 5 x 10 bit ADC.